# Undefined variable defined inside an 'if' not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this might have a really simple answer but I can't seem to figure it out.

I need to define the contents of a variable depending on the value of a parameter coming to a function.

The issue is that when I set my values inside an `if` I get `ReferenceError: newval is not defined`

Below is a simplified version of the code which runs the error:

```
    const myMessage = (recipientId, msg, miller) => {
      const tip = 1;
      if (tip===1) 
        {
        console.log("in here");
        const newval = "some value";
        }
      console.log("executes this");
      const send = newval;
```

When I check the console I get the `in here` before the `execute this` message. That is why I am not sure why `send` doesn't know what `newval` is.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: `const` and `let` are block scoped, they are not hoisted like `var`

Comment: I wonder how people decide to use new language features without learning about them first...

Comment: @FelixKling I wonder what your definition on learning might be. For me, posting questions about my learning experience in order to seek an answer is learning :)

Comment: Primarily for me: reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const): *"Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement."*.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, with tomorrow newspaper I could do much more than arrive to that URL. The thing is that before asking I was not aware that const was the issue so there was no way for me to arrive to that part of the documentation. Maybe built better documentations, with findable user cases and I won't have to bother (?) you anymore :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. My point was rather how someone can know and use `const` without knowing that it's blocked scoped. I see similar issues with other new features, such as arrow functions. And I just wonder how people pick up these new features without making themselves familiar with them first. Or if they do, then there must be incomplete documentation somewhere.

Comment: @FelixKling I was trying to understand an example from a library and adapt it to my needs.

Comment: I see... I guess that's the curse of using existing code without trying to analyze it first ;) I believe many people do that unfortunately :-/ I mean, weren't you curious about what `const` does JS if you haven't used it before?

Comment: The fact that I posted this question means that I indeed analyzed the code ;) Constants in many other languages work differently that how they do in JS. I assumed it was equal to what I already knew. As it was not, I had to ask :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`let` and `const` are both sensibly block-scoped, unlike `var`, so you cannot reference them outside of the surrounding **block** (*not function*):

```
function scopes() {
  if (true) {
    var foo = 'visible';
    let bar = 'not visible';
    console.log(foo, bar); // both foo and bar are visible
  }
  console.log(foo, bar); // foo is visible, bar is not
}
console.log(foo, bar); // neither foo nor bar are visible
```

If you want to set `const` to the result of a branch, try moving the branch to a small function and call that:

```
function getNewValue(tip) {
  if (tip === 1) {
    // do stuff
    return "some value";
  } else {
    // do other stuff
    return "other value";
  }
}

const tip = 1;
const send = getNewValue(tip);
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you declare let and const above the block ( if you need them outside the block )

Don't forget that **const** and **let** are block level and are also NOT hoisted. **var** is scope level and hoisted.

Here's a nice link about hoisting, if you're not familiar with it:
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

```
'use strict';
 const myMessage = (recipientId, msg, miller) => {
   const tip = 1;
   let newval;
   if (tip === 1) {
     console.log("in here");
     newval = "some value";
   }
   console.log("executes this");
   const send = newval;
 }
 myMessage()
```